# Flush Universal Image Loader cache

Tags: java, android, universal-image-loader

I'm using a volley singleton to load images

```
 private VolleySingleton(){
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(VolleyApplication.getAppContext());

        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
            private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> mCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(10);
            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                mCache.put(url, bitmap);
            }
            public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                return mCache.get(url);
            }
        });
    }
```

I need to flush the cache to update the imageView when the photo is changed.

I've read about [MemoryCacheUtils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987479/how-to-force-a-cache-clearing-using-universal-image-loader-android) here but can't seem to implment it in my code, can I use MemoryCacheUtils in my code? if not is there a way to flush the cache in my imageLoader?

**Edit**

Exposing the LruCache

```
  private VolleySingleton(){
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(VolleyApplication.getAppContext());

        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
            private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> mCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(10);
            public void flushLruCache(){ mCache.evictAll();};
            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                mCache.put(url, bitmap);
            }
            public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                return mCache.get(url);
            }
        });
    }
```

I'm trying to access it with ImageLoader.ImageCache flush = (ImageLoader.ImageCache) mImageLoader;

I can't access it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) has the method [evictAll()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html#evictAll()), you could just expose this method in your ImageLoader subclass to clear the cache.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble accessing the new method, I've edit my code above, have I exposed it correctly.