# Android: Universal image loader overrides old image

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

The user can upload an image and I want to display the image in a listview. This is the code so far:

```
final String urlForImage = baseUrlForImage + jsonObject.get("imageName");
new DownloadImageTask(cell.imageViewCustomer).execute(urlForImage);
final DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
    .cacheOnDisc(true).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
    .showImageForEmptyUri(cell.imageViewCustomer.getDrawable())
    .showImageOnFail(cell.imageViewCustomer.getDrawable())
    .showImageOnLoading(cell.imageViewCustomer.getDrawable()).build();
imageLoader.displayImage(urlForImage, cell.imageViewCustomer, options);
```

But now if the user uploads a new image, the older one from the cache will be loaded in the listview and the new image will be loaded every time from the internet.

How can I override the old image from the user, if the user uploads a new image?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987479/how-to-force-a-cache-clearing-using-universal-image-loader-android) could help you. Cleaning the cache (or a part of) sounds like a good way.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to change the url of the image, just add `?v=1` at the end and increment the number each time the user changes the image.