# android universal image loader clear cache

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

i use universal image loader to load image from url
this is adapter

```
public class BinderDataImg extends BaseAdapter {

static final String KEY_IMG = "img";
LayoutInflater inflater;
List<HashMap<String,String>> imgHashmap;
ViewHolder holder;

ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

public BinderDataImg(Activity act, List<HashMap<String,String>> map) {
    this.imgHashmap = map;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) act
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return imgHashmap.size();
}

public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null){
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_img, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.iv_img =(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageViewImg);

        vi.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{

        holder = (ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
    }

    String uri = imgHashmap .get(position).get(KEY_IMG);

    imageLoader.displayImage(uri, holder.iv_img);

    return vi;
}

static class ViewHolder{
    ImageView iv_img;
}
```

}

this is activity

```
List<ClassImg> imgList = null;
DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheOnDisk(true).cacheInMemory(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300))
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.hinh_error)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.hinh_internet)
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.hinh_loading)
            .build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
            .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
            .threadPoolSize(3)
            .diskCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024)
            .build();

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

    final CustomListView lvi = (CustomListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewHinh);

    try {
        XmlPullParser parser = new XmlPullParser();
        imgList = parser.parse(getAssets().open(file_xml);
        BinderDataImg binderdata = new BinderDataImg(this, imgHashmap);
        lvi.setAdapter(binderdata);

    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I can load image and image cache in memory and disk is perfect.
but I want when activity start cache will clear or when press back button to leave activity will delete cache in memory and cache in disk.
how to do that?
sorry for my bad English
thank for reading.

Comment: You dont need to clear the cache by your self, because the system will do that for you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19512974/1739882

Comment: @thunder413 : it's right?

Comment: @chintan soni : I already see it, but it's not exactly solution I find

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `DiskCacheUtils` and `MemoryCacheUtils` to remove specific image by image url

```
DiskCacheUtils.removeFromCache(imageUrl, ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiskCache());    
MemoryCacheUtils.removeFromCache(imageUrl, ImageLoader.getInstance().getMemoryCache());
```

or to completely clean cache

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().clearMemoryCache()
ImageLoader.getInstance().clearDiskCache()
```

To clear cache when activity created you can call this methods after you initialized your `ImageLoader`

To clear cache on leaving the activity you can call methods in `onDestroy ()` , but i should mind that system can kill your activity without calling this method.

Comment: add second solution after ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config); in activity?

Comment: You should look tip  #4 at https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Useful-Info

Answer (score 0):

ImageLoader class has two methods to clear caches: `clearMemoryCache` and `clearDiscCache`. Call them in activity `onDestroy` method will do what you are looking for.

Comment: but when load activity again, log cat show Try to initialize ImageLoader which had already been initialized before. To re-init ImageLoader with new. what's that? and some image load again and OutOfMemory error.

Comment: To avoid "already been initialized" message put your configuration part into a class that extends `Application` instead of your activity.

Comment: I don't understand, can you explant it?